# Bootstrap 3 fluid container issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a site using Bootstrap 3 framework, and I have a section that requires two fluid containers side by side with different background colours on each section. One of these containers is to contain a background image (see screenshot of section for reference).

Then on top of these two containers I require a normal container with my content so that it matches the rest of the websites positioning. I am unsure how to structurally develop this using Bootstrap framework.

**Screenshot**:

[image: screenshot]

**My code**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">background</div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            <div id="servicesSlider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <h1 class="arrow">Responsive Design Specialists</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies nulla non metus pulvinar imperdiet. Praesent non adipiscing libero.</p>
                        <p>Mauris ultrices odio vitae nulla ultrices iaculis. Nulla rhoncus odio eu lectus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas ornare augue vitae sollicitudin accumsan.</p>
                        <p>Etiam eget libero et erat eleifend consectetur a nec lectus. Sed id tellus lorem. Suspendisse sed venenatis odio, quis lobortis eros.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1 class="arrow">Bootstrap Professionals</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies nulla non metus pulvinar imperdiet. Praesent non adipiscing libero.</p>
                        <p>Mauris ultrices odio vitae nulla ultrices iaculis. Nulla rhoncus odio eu lectus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas ornare augue vitae sollicitudin accumsan.</p>
                        <p>Etiam eget libero et erat eleifend consectetur a nec lectus. Sed id tellus lorem. Suspendisse sed venenatis odio, quis lobortis eros.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check **[this:](http://jsfiddle.net/vp5qx/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">background</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 whitesmoke col-xs-offset-1">
        <div id="servicesSlider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                     <h1 class="arrow">Responsive Design Specialists</h1>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies nulla non metus pulvinar imperdiet. Praesent non adipiscing libero.</p>
                        <p>Mauris ultrices odio vitae nulla ultrices iaculis. Nulla rhoncus odio eu lectus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas ornare augue vitae sollicitudin accumsan.</p>
                        <p>Etiam eget libero et erat eleifend consectetur a nec lectus. Sed id tellus lorem. Suspendisse sed venenatis odio, quis lobortis eros.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row pinklight" id="onTop">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             <h1 class="arrow">Bootstrap Professionals</h1>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies nulla non metus pulvinar imperdiet. Praesent non adipiscing libero.</p>
            <p>Mauris ultrices odio vitae nulla ultrices iaculis. Nulla rhoncus odio eu lectus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas ornare augue vitae sollicitudin accumsan.</p>
            <p>Etiam eget libero et erat eleifend consectetur a nec lectus. Sed id tellus lorem. Suspendisse sed venenatis odio, quis lobortis eros.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 div#onTop {
     position:absolute;
     top:10px;
 }
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     div#onTop {
         width: 750px;
     }
 }
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     div#onTop {
         width: 970px;
     }
 }
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     div#onTop {
         width: 1170px;
     }
 }
 .whitesmoke {
     background-color:whitesmoke
 }
 .pinklight {
     background-color:rgba(239, 201, 201, 0.5);
 }
```